# Javascript websocket not connecting

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to make a simple chat application

I have a server made with Spring running with a websocket

I've also made an android app that successfully connects to the websocket and receives and sends messages

To make testing easier I decided to make a web client for the server in html/js, but the websocket connection fails

I'm using the exact same address as I am in the android app

Heres my JS code:

```
$( document ). ready(function(){

    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.3:8080/chatwebsocket")

    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        var msg = event.data
        $("#chat_container").append(`<p>$(msg.sender): $(msg.content))</p>`)
    }

    ws.onerror =  function (event) {
        console.log('WebSocket error: ', event);
    }

    ws.onclose = function (event) {
        console.log('WebSocket closed: ', event);
    }


    $("#message_form").onsubmit = function(data) {
        var msgContent = data.messageContent
        var msg = {"sender":"webclient", "content": msgContent}
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg))
    }
})
```

I've tested it with Chrome and Firefox and both fail
Chrome just gives the message: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.3:8080/chatwebsocket' failed:`

Theres no useful info in either the error or close events

No connection is made on the server side

The web client successfully connects to wss://ws.postman-echo.com/raw for an example

Can someone please point me in the right direction with troubleshooting this because I feel like I have no info to work with

Comment: Have you tried opening https://192.168.1.3:8080 in your browser? It may be chrome blocking you based on your ssl cert if its self signed/ untrusted

Comment: Hello @nathan.medz, yes, and it opens it just fine

Comment: Ok, I noticed that it does connect only if I'm accessing the page from the IP address of the server, and not if I'm just opening index.html from my local files